# After scrolling, touch is detected in the wrong area (iPad / Website)

Tags: jquery, html, ios, ipad, viewport

I'm not sure why at all. I tried disabling pretty much every bit of code on my site with no luck. This is my first time developing for an iPad.

When the user scrolls down, even one pixel, then the menu can be activated about 50px below the menu while ALSO still being able to work directly on the menu. It's like it then detects the menu in two places while it is only in one?

Has anyone ever heard of an issue like this?

The website is http://fastgateopeners.com and the issue happens on an iPad in landscape. Not any Android tablets/phones and not on an iPhone.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I have just checked your problem that you have described and it seems to work fine on my ipad :)

Comment: Really? In landscape mode if you scroll down slightly you can't trigger the menu (where the menu items turn white) from like an inch below the menu? Oh man if it's just my works iPad I will be so happy.

Comment: Yep not happening for me my friend :)

Comment: But I would just check it on another ipad. As I'm running mine slightly different to normal due to development. I wouldn't want it to be wrong for your customers